# Vue's render createElement gives error when passed a regular Vue file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, render, createelement

So I created a Vue file with a render function that is supposed to loop over IDs and create components according to those.

Specifically inside my render function I'm using `createElement` to which I pass three params:

1. A Vue component (from a JS file)
2. a config object
3. A Vue component (from a Vue file)

**It's 3. that's giving me this error:**

> Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

this Vue file has no render function, but it does have a `template`, so I'm confused why this error is happening.

In the code below `[createElement([dialogs[id]])]` is the part that gives the error:

```js
import { QDialog } from 'quasar'
import Signin from './Signin.vue'
import Signout from './Signout.vue'

const dialogs = {
  Signin,
  Signout
}

function createDialogNode (id, createElement, parent) {
  return createElement(QDialog, {
    props: {
      value: parent.toggles[id]
    },
    on: {
      input: function (newState) {
        parent.toggles[id] = newState
      }
    }
  }, [createElement([dialogs[id]])])
}

// further down I use `createDialogNode` inside the render function and loop over the props inside `dialogs`.
```

So in the code above you see I have an object `dialogs` with imported components. These components are regular Vue files.

I want to pass them inside `createElement` as third param to the other `createElement` that is returned in my function above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass an array to `createElement` as the first argument.

Try this instead:

```
createElement(dialogs[id])
```

Comment: Thanks so much Decade Moon!! (Your upvote is much appreciated )